# How to set url from ajax form to specific action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want set from the following form:

```
<%= form_for(:userrole, :remote => true, :url => ....) do %>
```

the url so, that in the controller("topic") a specific action e.g. save_userrole will called.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `<%= form_for(:userrole, :remote => true, :url => {:action => "save_userrole"}) do %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag save_userrole_topic_path, remote: true do %>
...
<%- end %>
```

or if you have an object:

```
<%= form_for @userrole, remote: true, url: save_userrole_topic_path(@userrole do %>
....
<%- end %>
```

but usually you have a rest resource in your routes like

```
resources :userroles
```

and then you end doing in your views

```
<%= form_for @userrole, remote :true do %>
...
<%- end %>
```

which will hit the action **save** in your userroles controller

last resource, you can write the url manually if needed (although if there is a route, you don't need it at all)

```
<%= form_for @userrole, remote: true, url: '/topics/save_userrole' do %>
...
<%- end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**rake routes** and just specify url + **_path** for required controller#action in form.

For example:

```
$ rake routes
...
save_user_role    POST      /topic/:user_id    topic#save_userrole
```

and

```
<%= form_for(:userrole, remote: true, url: save_user_role_path) do %>
```